# Как избежать авторизации по украденному куки?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Я новичек и не понимаю как избежать "взлома" по украденному куки, допустим я регистрирую пользователя , сохраняю все в бд и делаю уникальный куки, отправляю его пользователю и по  этому куки пользователь может получать всю необходимую информацию, но если этот куки украдут, то все, вор сможет также получить всю инфу, как этого избежать и пофиксить?

Comment: задать время жизни куки

Comment: Почитай о JWT: [тык](https://jwt.io).

Comment: @Владислав jwt тоже можно украсть) а если обновлять его на каждом запросе, то проблем ещё больше наберется

Comment: @eri Ну не при каждом запросе, а через пару минут) Вк, гугля и прочие как-то же работают.

Answer (score 0):

У любой системы есть слабые места и абсолютной гарантии вам никто не даст. Но если выполнять нижеперечисленные условия, то украсть авторизационные куки будет весьма сложно.

- Настроить SSL (https)
- Включить HSTS
- Куки передаются с `secure` флагом
- `httponly` в true при передаче. В этом случае JS на клиенте не будет иметь доступа к кукам